# Flutter commands delay on Windows and git-remote-https.exe process

Tags: git, flutter, dart

Good and CoronaVirus-Free day to everyone,

I have been experiencing a noticeable delay every time I run any flutter commands on windows 10.
I tried to find the reason for that, open task manager and I run **flutter --version** in the windows command line.
I noticed a new process starts every time I run flutter command, The process called: "**git-remote-https.exe**"

I tried to investigate it, I switched to another task manager for windows called "**Process Explorer**" and I open properties for "**git-remote-https.exe**" process to get more information about it. I took this screenshot :

[image: flutter git-remote-https]

In the Command line section, you see that flutter is trying to get remote data from flutter.git repository,
I don't know why this behavior is happening, considering that I have flutter SDK already downloaded at : D:\Flutter\sdk\ and I don't need to download any more data as far as I know.

I noticed that "**git-remote-https**" process downloads about **1.5MB** of data every time it runs and then terminates. I have to wait for the download to finish before getting the result of commands like "**flutter --version**" as if I am getting the result from a remote server.

Can you please help me with this?
I am using flutter version 1.15.17 on the beta channel. 
I have been experiencing this behavior only recently, for the last week

I run 'flutter doctor -v',
waited for sometime, about +2 minutes, I guess for 'git-remote-https.exe' process to finish
and here is the response :

```
C:\Users\Rami>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.15.17, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.15.17 at D:\Flutter\sdk
    • Framework revision 2294d75bfa (4 weeks ago), 2020-03-07 00:28:38 +0900
    • Engine revision 5aff311948
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.12.0 9983424a3c)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Rami\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM A520F   • 192.168.8.80:5555 • android-arm64  • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)
    • Chrome     • chrome            • web-javascript • Google Chrome 80.0.3987.162
    • Web Server • web-server        • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

• No issues found!
```

Thank you

Comment: flutter issue filed here : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53733

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with flutter on windows but you could try deleting git and installing it via

```
sudo apt install git
```

Comment: Tells me if that doesn't work, flutter builds itself on the first use of the flutter command. You could delete the folder it builds itself in too, don't know if this helps. Delete files in the .pub-cache